# FND_VAULT package

Tags: oracle, encryption

I have to encrypt my SOAP message and send to destination and the respective decrypt algorithm should run there. I went through fnd_vault package of oracle but no where I got any useful Information so can anyone please provide me some material or way to deal with this package.

I know I am not expected to ask such question here, but I didn't find any post regarding fnd_vault package so have to post neither I got some satisfactory information after goggling on it. So thought that some discussion regarding this can be done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use TLS/SSL. Depending on what technology you use, you may need to select appropriate driver. I would start from [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=oracle+connection+ssl).

#### Example 1

You use web services that wraps database API. In this case use HTTPS connection and make sure that service side is configured to accept SSL connection (which means you need to install a trusted certificate on the web server).

#### Example 2

You use Java driver to directly connect to Oracle server. Use [this manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) to configure JDBC connection.

Comment: No problem, I would wait a bit, maybe someone will come up with a better solution. But generally speaking, this is how you do this across many different technologies, when you want to make two nodes talk to each other in a secure fashion.